# Postgres 10.5: Create Materialized View where column data may be empty/null?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I am creating a Materialized View from two tables, using the `array_agg` function to join strings from `table_b` to `table_a`. Essentially, `column_c` on `table_a` is a nullable array of numbers corresponding to the `id` column of `table_b` (which has only two columns, `id` and `description`). However, the Materialized View fails to include a row for any row on `table_a` that is null / empty on `column_c`.

Is it possible to make the Materialized either (1) enter an empty array; or (2) a null value, when `table_a` `column_c` value is null?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_materialized_view
AS
SELECT
  id,
  column_a,
  column_b,
  array_agg(description) as column_c
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b on table_b.id = any(column_c)
GROUP BY table_a.id
ORDER BY table_a.id ASC
WITH DATA;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_materialized_view
AS
SELECT
  id,
  column_a,
  column_b,
  array_agg(description) as column_c
  -- or
  -- coalesce(array_agg(description), '{}') as column_c
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b on table_b.id = any(column_c)
GROUP BY table_a.id
ORDER BY table_a.id ASC
WITH DATA;
```

Comment: For others like myself who need a refresher in JOIN types: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/